# Disable click on # link with hoverintent

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

How would you disable the link when clicked on this code I made for an image fade in using hoverintent. I'm using an named anchor now but it jumps so I'd like to disable the click.

```
<A class="next2 nextbuttonB" href="#top">INSTALL</A>
<A class="next2 nextbuttonA" href="#top">ESTIMATE</A>
```

and the jquery

```
$('#A,#B,').addClass('nextHide');

$('.nextbuttonA').hoverIntent(function() {
$('#A').fadeIn("slow");$('#B').fadeOut();
}, function() {
$('#B').hide();
});

$('.nextbuttonB').hoverIntent(function() {
$('#B').fadeIn("slow");$('#A').fadeOut();
}, function() {
$('#A').hide();
});     

$('.nextbutton').hoverIntent(function() {
$('#A,#B').fadeOut();
}, function() {
$('#A,#B').hide();
}); 

$('#A,#B').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#A,#B').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` or `return false` will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Either do a

`return false;`

or pass in the event as `e` to your `function` and do a `e.preventDefault()` like this:

```
$('.next2').click(
    function(e){
       e.preventDefault(); //return false; //would also work
       //then do other stuff
});
```

Also, why use `#top`? if you don't want it to behave like a named anchor? You could just use:

`<a href="javascript:void(0)">...</a>`

Comment: simply using <a href="#" >..</a> will not jump as well.

Comment: You need hash mark link for the hover with just a hash mark as the link it goes to the top of the document, so a named anchor at least get's it closer. jsvoid and preventDefault kills the hover style on the link.

Answer (score 2):

try this
change/add selector as needed

```
$("#A,#B").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: That stops the hover style as well. So you click on the link it changes color but doesn't change back...